# Change responseType in Axios based on response

Tags: javascript, axios

I've an [axios request](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) with `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` this works correctly when response is a success 200.

However when the api I'm accessing and returns a 500 with a json object - axios encodes that in an arraybuffer.

My current workaround is to use an arraybuffer-to-string library to decode the json error message. **Is there a better way to do this? Prevent axios from converting response to the defined responseType?**

I've tried [response interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#Interceptors) and there is also an [open issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/793) for axios to infer response types which would be great because if it saw `application/json` content-type and resolved it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution.
In catch you can convert the arraybuffer response to json by this:

```
const data = await JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(error.response.data));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.get('https://testapi.com/api/xyz',
    {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/pdf'
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        //response
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

see if this helps